# Command line output in python read line by line with each value in the line put into an array and recalled

Tags: python, arrays, split

I'm trying to capture the output of a command and have each line in an array so I can evaluate on a position in the line as a constant if that makes sense. It would treat the output almost as columns.

I've basically assigned a command output to a variable and split it on each line. I can do a split and get the first "column" but I can't seem to get past this.

I've broken the code into sections to show the output I'm seeing. I'm running an aureport to evaluate some login activity.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import platform
import fnmatch
import subprocess

results = subprocess.check_output("aureport -ts yesterday -te now  -au -i --failed", shell=True).splitlines()
print(results)


for line in results:
  print(line)

for line in results:
  arg = line.split(' ')
  item1 = arg[0]
  print(item1)
exit(0)
```

The results I get are:

```
['', 'Authentication Report', '============================================', '# date time acct host term exe success event', '============================================', '1. 00/00/00 06:49:24 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid', '2. 00/00/00 06:49:27 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid', '3. 00/00/00 06:49:29 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid', '4. 00/00/00 07:10:44 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid', '5. 00/00/00 07:10:49 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid', '6. 00/00/00 07:10:53 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid', '7. 00/00/00 07:11:14 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid', '8. 00/00/00 07:11:16 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid', '9. 00/00/00 07:11:25 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid', '10. 00/00/00 06:19:44 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid', '11. 00/00/00 06:19:47 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid', '12. 00/00/00 06:20:59 some_user host command /some/command no some_pid', '13. 00/00/00 06:21:01 some_user ::1 command /some/command no some_pid']

Authentication Report
============================================
# date time acct host term exe success event
============================================
1. 00/00/00 06:49:24 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid
2. 00/00/00 06:49:27 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid
3. 00/00/00 06:49:29 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid
4. 00/00/00 07:10:44 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid
5. 00/00/00 07:10:49 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid
6. 00/00/00 07:10:53 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid
7. 00/00/00 07:11:14 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid
8. 00/00/00 07:11:16 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid
9. 00/00/00 07:11:25 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid
10. 00/00/00 06:19:44 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid
11. 00/00/00 06:19:47 some_user ? host /some/command no some_pid
12. 00/00/00 06:20:59 some_user host command /some/command no some_pid
13. 00/00/00 06:21:01 some_user ::1 command /some/command no some_pid

Authentication
============================================
#
============================================
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
7.
8.
9.
10.
11.
12.
13.
```

What I would like to do is create some evaluations on (as an example) the 'column' in the output that shows 'no' and then print output from the rest of the line. Example: `if arg[7] == 'no': print(arg[4])`

What I can't seem to wrap my head around is getting the output evaluated on line by line so arg[7] always refers to the 'no' column etc. I did manage to get just the first column by splitting on a space however I'm pretty sure it's coincidence :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, all you need to do is put your `if` statement within your `for` loop. Then it will evaluate the output line by line. So your last section could look like this:

```
for line in results[5:]:
    arg = line.split()
    if arg[7] == 'no':
        print(arg[4])
```

Note I changed `line.split(' ')` to `line.split()` as the default action of `split()` is to separate by whitespace.

The `[4:]` removes the lines you aren't considering: `'#####...'`, etc.

Comment: The problem is I'm not even returning a value for arg[anything other than 0]. What I did to test was tried assigning a variable to even arg[7]: ```for line in results:
        arg = line.split()
        item1 = arg[7]
        print(item1)
``` The output is just ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 15, in <module>
    item1 = arg[7]
IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: I also tried changing the ```line.split(' ')``` and I got the same error as above. With it in I get the output originally posted *confused*

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to achieve. Why do you want to assign something to `arg[1]`? What do you want to do with the evaluated data? Did you check the output of my solution?

Comment: I didn't _just_ change `split(' ')`: Check the `if` statement too. In your code you tried to take index 7 of the strings `'1:'`, `'2:'`, etc. which doesn't exist.

Comment: I was trying to assign arg[whatever] to a variable to evaluate on later. The output of your solution is the same as if I try to just print and value other than ```arg[0]``` : ```IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: Then you haven't copied the entire loop in my solution, only the changed `split(' ')` -> `split()`. My output is (as expected): `? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? host ::1`, whereby these are all printed on a new line.

Comment: To simplify: I'm trying to have every value in each line returned from the command be something I can reference. So the first column is a number, second is a date, 3rd is a time, 4th is a user name etc. As an example, print out all of the user column assumably ```arg[3]``` however anything other than ```arg[0]``` returns the same error

Comment: Brainfart on my part! Sorry. I missed the other three lines. The for loop should start like this: `for line in results[5:]:`. This isolates the outputs you're looking at.

Comment: That's IT!! Thank you!! this has been driving me nuts. Now I need to know why this works and what I broke in my own brain :D can you edit your solution to include the ```results[:5]

Comment: Use print statements at each step to see how the strings and lists are changing. The method `splitlines()` separates your output into a list of the separate lines. Taking `results[5:]` considers all items in `results` from the 5th item onwards (what does `print(results[4:])` look like?). Then you split each line by whitespace and have a list of the individual strings. Then you perform an if statement on the list generated from each individual line.